# String constants in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, text, ascii

Does Haskell have a function for getting a list of all punctuation characters, and all whitespace characters, like Python's [string constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants)?

Comment: Haskell's `Char` type is Unicode, not ASCII. Does that have any impact on your question?

Comment: @Carl I suppose it doesn't really matter for my use case. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: `filter isPunctuation $ map chr [0..0x10FFFF]` etc

Comment: What I'm looking for is `filter isPrint $ map chr [0..128]`. Thanks!

Comment: Why `map chr` when you can `['\0' .. '\128']` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Data.Char](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isControl) has predicates for punctuation, whitespace, and all of the Unicode character classes.  As others suggested in comments, you can use these with `filter`, and restrict the list to ASCII if that is all you want.